# How to build an app?

Tags: build

I just discover Sphero and I'm in love. So I want to build apps. The only problem is that I don't know what software use or what coding language to know so I need help!

Comment: please google a little before posting such questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit way too vague. You can build an app with honestly ANY language out there. The term 'app' is just a collection of programs that are set together to create one big bundle of files that will run on a device supporting it. For example the files ending in .ipa are for the iPhone applications, the files .app are for mac applications, usually written in obj-c, the ending in .exe are executable files that are most commonly ran on windows, and so forth. Things like .java, .c, .cpp, .m, .h, and so forth are used to bundle together to create the big files like the .app, .exe, and .ipa.

To make an app, there are many websites that offer interactive ideas for apps, or all you have to do is search mobile app making on google, or even just learning a programming language as simple as Java(desktop, mobile, anything), javascript(web,internet), or even something like c/c++(desktop,3d games,etc).

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem :) what kind of application are you wanting to build?

Comment: Mostly Sphero games, I had some ideas but I need to learn a coding language..

Comment: ok, well I just looked up Sphero, and since most of it is for iOS and Android, I would say learn Java /or Objective-c for developing on both platforms.

Comment: Yes, Java is a very good language to know, mostly because almost every company has a Java developer needed. Also because it runs on any platform. Very useful, but objective-c is only for iPhone, so you can only use Java on the android device platform